# How to extract key and value for one dictionary in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have one dictionary with multiple keys but I just want to get the key and value of one of them and create a new dictionary with just that key and value (I don't need to pop or remove old values from the old dictionary).

How can I do it?

```
dictionary2 = dictionary1["expectedkey"]
```

This code just gives me the key value but I'm trying just to create a new dictionary with both key and value. I know I can always do it manually like this:

```
dictionary2 = {"expectedkey": dictionary1["expectedkey"]}
```

Just I wonder if there is a more straightforward way to do it as I just started with Python a couple of weeks ago and I'm quite sure there sould be a more simple way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: That's the straight forward way you have coded

Comment: I'm wondering how a one item dictionary will be helpful to you?

Comment: Well, it's actually json from a request and I just want to send a new request with just one of the values from the dictionary as the others shouldn't be sent.